# Sails.js/Redis: How to implement secondary indexing

Tags: indexing, redis, sails.js, waterline

I am using `sails-redis` adapter. How can I set a secondary index for an attribute in a model and fetch the data accordingly?

Comment: I don't think you can, sails is a simple storage API, can you consider using another client driver?

Comment: @GuyKorland no I can't. Feel free to suggest one though!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the Sails Redis adapter, so take my advice with a grain of salt. Based on their public documentation, it seems like it does not support any form of indexing - it's just a wrapper around the core Redis commands:

> This adapter does not support the Semantic or Queryable interfaces. Instead, it simply provides robust, managed access to the underlying Redis client.

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-redis

As such, you'll have to manually create secondary indices. Redis provides a number of data structures that come in handy here, such as sorted sets, sets, and lists.

I wrote a bit of [an article](https://www.memurai.com/blog/model-hash-attributes-using-secondary-indexes-in-redis-and-memurai) about how to create those indices, which might be a useful read.